# Passing index row to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my UItableView I want pass to `SecondViewController` the Row index.
The problem is that:
 prepareForSegue is called after than didSelectRowAtIndexPath so the result of screenNumber is "nil"

**Table :**

```
 class ViewController: UITableViewController{
        var FirstTableArray = [String]()
        var nextScreenRow: NSInteger?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            FirstTableArray = ["first","second","third"]
        }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return FirstTableArray.count
        }
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

            Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]

            return Cell
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
            nextScreenRow = indexPath.row

        }

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

            if (segue.identifier == "Cell") {

                println("nextScreenRow")

                var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;

                detailController.screenNumber = nextScreenRow

            }
         }
    }
```

**SecondViewController**:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var screenNumber: NSInteger!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        println("screenNumber")

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if (segue.identifier == "Cell") {


            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;

            if let ip = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow { //ERROR

                detailController.screenNumber = ip.row //ERROR
            }

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, inside `prepareForSegue` call `indexPathForSelectedRow` on `tableView` object:

```
...
if let ip = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    ...
    detailController.screenNumber = ip.row
}
...
```

For Swift 1.2 use:

```
tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
```

Comment: @Sarita can you log it: print("Row: \\(ip.row)")

Comment: Error in the first string: Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Opional type     and () -> NSIndexPath? does not have a member named row @Greg

Comment: @Sarita can you post all prepareForSegue method?

Comment: ` override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        
        if (segue.identifier == "Cell") {


            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;

            if let ip = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                
                detailController.screenNumber = ip.row
            }
            
        }
        

    } `

Comment: Check the question @Greg

Comment: @Sarita just to let you know in your viewDIdLoad method the println is wrong and it won't print the row no, only static text.

Comment: It doens't mean.. MY project have right println(screenNumber)

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? Try if let ip = tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: Try detailController.screenNumber = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row and remove if let syntax

Comment: Do you use Swift 1.2? If so this should work tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row

Comment: This won't work with latest Swift but my answer will. I assumed that your question is about Swift 2.